# Regex to match 15 digit number starting with 3

Tags: vb.net

Anyone, please help.

Sample Input Text:

```
Material    Description     Serial No.  QTY 
2000567     ABC         355732080564940     1 
2000567     ABC         355732080565020     1 
2000567     ABC         155732080579401     1 
2000567     ABC         155732080579625     1
```

I would like to match the 15 digit numbers in the above string. But those 15 digit number that starts with 3.

Expected Output:

```
355732080564940     
355732080565020
```

I tried ^3\d{14}$ , but not working

Thanks

Comment: I tried this 

(3)(\d{14}) 

and it works

Comment: I suggest you to use https://regexr.com/ when you have to work on a Regex, it is usefull. @spinanoop response seems to be OK !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `^3\d{14}$` , but not working

That's because `^` means "start of input" and `$` means "end of input"

The serial number is not at the start of input; the material and description are before it, so it will never work out

Just use

```
3\d{14}
```

..you don't need all the brackets you put in your commented solution either